# Angular 5 mdbootstrap autocomplete error " no value accessor for form control with name: 'autocomplete'"

Tags: angular, typescript, mdbootstrap

I am trying to implement the mdbootstrap pro version autocomplete but its giving error " no value accessor for form control with name: 'autocomplete'" for this I tried several ways but no luck, please help to get rid of this.

```
<mdb-autocomplete [label]="'Select color'" initialValue="Select color"
  name="autocomplete" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" 
   [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0">
</mdb-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Check if the dependencies are correctly installed.

Comment: @MadaZZ All dependencies are installed properly

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with MDB PRO package and works like a charm. Which version do you use and are you sure that you use MDB PRO (not MDB aka MDB Free).

As per the docs: 
https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/forms/autocomplete/

Autocompleted is available in MDB PRO

Comment: I am using mdbootstrap 4.5.0, can you tell which selector you are using to instantiate autpcomplete